# Difference between log methods

Tags: java, android

I am new in android and i print log-cat using:

```
Log.w("Tag", "String text");
```

and log text print but after searching for a time i find some more way to print logcat like:

```
Log.v() 
Log.d()
```

and now i am confuse in these methods.

Which is the best method for print log-cat and how may method for print lagcat and also what is the main difference between them?

Comment: you should first read android documentation carefully before asking question here...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: There is an excellent article on that http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#log-sparingly The link posted by himanshu isn't great help as well as his behavior towards newcomers on SE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

commonly used `Log` methods are  five :

`Log.v ()` **VERBOSE**

`Log.d ()` **DEBUG**

`Log.i ()` **INFO**

`Log.w ()` **WARN**

`Log.e ()` **ERROR**

**1:** `Log.v` - debugging ***color black*** , and any messages will be output, where v represents the verbose verbose mean, usually is Log.v ("", "");

**2:** `Log.d` - the output ***color is blue*** , the only output debug debugging meaning, but he would output the upper filter up through of DDMS Logcat label to select.

**3:** `Log.i` - output ***color is green*** , general tips, news information, it does not the output Log.v Log.d information, but will display the information of i, w and e

**4:** `Log.w` - mean ***orange*** , can be seen as a warning The warning, in general we need to optimize the Android code, and will output it after Log.e.

**5:** `Log.e` - is ***red*** , you can think of error error here only to show the red error message, these errors we need careful analysis.

For more information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: And even more information: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#log-sparingly

Answer (score 5):

The various single-letter methods indicate the *severity* of the log message. Subsequently, you can filter log messages based on both the tag and the severity, and prevent lesser-severity messages from being shown in your released application (for example).

For more information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in severity;

```
Log.e() will simply log an error to the log with priority ERROR.
```

Generally, use the `Log.v() Log.d() Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e()` methods.

The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is `ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE. Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development. Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info logs are always kept.`

Answer (score 0):

```
int ASSERT Priority constant for the println method.
int DEBUG Priority constant for the println method; use Log.d.
int ERROR Priority constant for the println method; use Log.e.
int INFO Priority constant for the println method; use Log.i.
int VERBOSE Priority constant for the println method; use Log.v.
int WARN Priority constant for the println method; use Log.w.
```

Comment: Mind to add some words of explanation?