# Can't catch Java (Android) Exception with try-catch

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception, try-catch

I'm a Java (Android) beginner (coming from Python) and I'm trying to catch an exception using Try-Catch as follows:

```
try {
    u.save();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.wtf("DO THIS", " WHEN SAVE() FAILS");
}
```

To my surprise I don't see my Log message but I still get the following error:

> 09-25 10:53:32.147: E/SQLiteDatabase(7991):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19:
>   constraint failed

Why doesn't it catch the Exception? Am I doing something wrong here? All tips are welcome!

The save() method looks as follows:

```
public final void save() {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = Cache.openDatabase();
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    for (Field field : mTableInfo.getFields()) {
        final String fieldName = mTableInfo.getColumnName(field);
        Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();

        field.setAccessible(true);

        try {
            Object value = field.get(this);

            if (value != null) {
                final TypeSerializer typeSerializer = Cache.getParserForType(fieldType);
                if (typeSerializer != null) {
                    // serialize data
                    value = typeSerializer.serialize(value);
                    // set new object type
                    if (value != null) {
                        fieldType = value.getClass();
                        // check that the serializer returned what it promised
                        if (!fieldType.equals(typeSerializer.getSerializedType())) {
                            Log.w(String.format("TypeSerializer returned wrong type: expected a %s but got a %s",
                                    typeSerializer.getSerializedType(), fieldType));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // TODO: Find a smarter way to do this? This if block is necessary because we
            // can't know the type until runtime.
            if (value == null) {
                values.putNull(fieldName);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Byte.class) || fieldType.equals(byte.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (Byte) value);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Short.class) || fieldType.equals(short.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (Short) value);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Integer.class) || fieldType.equals(int.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (Integer) value);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Long.class) || fieldType.equals(long.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (Long) value);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Float.class) || fieldType.equals(float.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (Float) value);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Double.class) || fieldType.equals(double.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (Double) value);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Boolean.class) || fieldType.equals(boolean.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (Boolean) value);
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Character.class) || fieldType.equals(char.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, value.toString());
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(String.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, value.toString());
            }
            else if (fieldType.equals(Byte[].class) || fieldType.equals(byte[].class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, (byte[]) value);
            }
            else if (ReflectionUtils.isModel(fieldType)) {
                values.put(fieldName, ((Model) value).getId());
            }
            else if (ReflectionUtils.isSubclassOf(fieldType, Enum.class)) {
                values.put(fieldName, ((Enum<?>) value).name());
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e);
        }
    }

    if (mId == null) {
        mId = db.insert(mTableInfo.getTableName(), null, values);
    }
    else {
        db.update(mTableInfo.getTableName(), values, "Id=" + mId, null);
    }

    Cache.getContext().getContentResolver()
            .notifyChange(ContentProvider.createUri(mTableInfo.getType(), mId), null);
}
```

Comment: Did you see your log message as well?

Comment: @Henry - No I don't see the error message at all. (added it to my question).

Comment: Try replacing "wtf" with "e" - you should then see your message. There is nothing wrong with your try/catch. Unless the u.save method already catches the exception and handles it

Comment: Can you show us the `save` method?

Comment: may be the exception is getting caught inside your `save` method

Comment: @Guillaume - wtf is a totally fine way of throwing errors that should never occur. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html for reference.

Comment: Oh well, Ok then :) WTF!

Comment: @Henry - I added the save() method to my question.

Comment: What do you want your program to do if the user left a blank field that shouldn't? You want the program to give him a polite advice and ask him to fill it correctly? You want to put a default value where the user left blank? What do you want the program to do?

Comment: @Math - In the current state (building and debugging) I want the program to give a big fat warning in Logcat, but in the future I might want to display a polite advice and/or log the error and send it back to us so that we know it occurs. The main thing is that I don't want the error to go unnoticed. And for it not to go unnoticed I need to be able to catch it somehow..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two classes to catch the problems.

1. Error
2. Exception

Both are sub-class of **Throwable** class. When there is situation we do not know, that particular code block will throw Exception or Error? You can use **Throwable**. **Throwable** will catch both **Errors** & **Exceptions**.

Do this way

```
try {
    u.save();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This gives the strange result that it doesn't show the SQLException, but it also doesn't show the Log message.. :S

Comment: It makes perfect sense + this just saved my day
Thank you!

Comment: Tip: if you're getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" in your code, use the "printStackTrace()" method above, just like the example. It will cast a light over your problems.

Comment: it wont help still my app is crashing when i try to get spinner value

Answer (score 1):

Constraint failed usually indicates that you did something like pass a `null` value into a column that you declare as not `null` when you create your table.

Comment: That's absolutely true. I am doing it on purpose because I want to cath this mistake when it occurs..

Comment: This answer is indeed usefull, but it doesn't solve my question. If you see the save() method, would you know how to catch the error?

Answer (score 1):

do this way

```
try {
    // do some thing which you want in try block
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Catch block", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
try {
u.save();

} catch (SQLException sqle) {
Log.wtf("DO THIS", " WHEN SAVE() FAILS");
}catch (Exception e) {
Log.wtf("DO THIS", " WHEN SAVE() FAILS");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Log is expecting certain variable-names like verbose(v), debug(d) or info(i).
Your "wtf" doesnt belong there. Check this answer for more info -->

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10006054/2074990

or this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: Although not often used, wtf is definitely a valid variable name. Check it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: LOL! now that is funny :-)