# What is the meaning of Log.i()

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm taking an Android Studio class, and the teacher taught me to do

```
Log.i("data", "onCreate called")
```

in the overriden methods. I just don't understand why.

This is the code of the whole thing:

```
package com.myfirstapplication.theclass4

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.i("data", "onCreate called")    //Log turns red -> Alt+Enter
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.i("data", "onStart called")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.i("data", "onResume called")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.i("data", "onPause called")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.i("data", "onStop called")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.i("data", "onDestroy called")
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, he probably added this when reflecting after class. It's not an unreasonable ask, even if the answer is simple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between log methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005950/difference-between-log-methods)

Comment: @NickCardoso: Thank you! He was teaching the onStart, OnPause,... I think he was just showing us how it looks like!

Comment: @Zoe: Thank you Zoe. It's my first day of this class, and the teacher didn't like answering questions very much, so....

Comment: Sorry to be years late, but this is a great and amazing question.  This question answered my search about recalling what `Log.i()` means upon seeing it undefined in a code-port of code I wrote myself.  This is just a great question.  Thank you for asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be needing something called "logcat" a lot whenever you're developing for Android.

Whenever you open Android Studio, you'll see something like this:

[image]

These are different levels of "problem"/information that you're logging, so that you can understand which code is being run, and if it is working as expected.

Now, you said why does `Log.i("key","value")` exist, and why you were told to do that.

It simply means, you logged an event, which was just for purposes of logging normal "information", as "i" in `Log.i` stands for Info.

There are different levels of severity of an event that you're trying to log.

So, for example, if you want to log an event that causes your app to crash, you'll log it with `Log.e("key","value");`, where "e" signifies and error.

There are different levels of severity which you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log).

Now, why do you need these different levels?

Simply, because you need to filter those depending on what you're trying to log. So if for example your application crashes, you'll be able to see it in "Error" section in the dropdown that is marked in the picture above. So you can say it's for organizing the data that you/the system is logging.

The first parameter in Logs is the key, so you can search for particular logs belonging to one category quickly through the search bar in logcat, the second parameter is for adding more information.

Example:

```
void multiply(){
   int a = 3*4;
   Log.i("multiplication","Value of a is:"+String.valueOf(a));
}
```

In your example, you were told to log stuff because your teacher was trying to teach you lifecycle of an activity, meaning, in which order the functions of activity are executed.

Comment: -1, What is the fully qualified package name of `Log` and why would I see a compile error in Android Studio that this symbol is missing instead of seeing a failure in my package imports.  Java standard is that a failure due to missing class implementation should be resolved in the package imports NOT in the code...  At least that's my understanding of Java practices.  Why is this `class Log` so special it should give me grief in code I wrote myself and then left sit for 5 years?  Why doesn't it follow the standard and what is it actually in code, not some language plugin "enhancement"?

Comment: I just realized the package name is actually in the question itself as an import statement. I was expecting a C# style fully qualified name in a line of implementation code e.g.: `android.util.Log.i("foo","bar was here");`. I did not read any of the links you provided, I thought your answer was already more than long enough. I've been using "trace logging statements" since before there was an android OS. Not that I actually understand "how things work". The I/O path from phone innards to IDE console window is pretty complicated. Some severities were `DBG_LOW` and `DBG_HIGH` back then.

Answer (score 0):

It means log a message to the **LogCat** with the **info** severity.

This information can be easily found in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) but you can read more about logcat in [this doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Comment: Thank you Nick. While I understand this question isn't a great one, but I don't mind if more knowledgable people look down on it.

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Thank you, so the fully qualified package is: `android.util.Log`  What docs should I be reading?  I thought this was Java, Do I need to read about IDE implementation to understand what a Java class is and where to find the .class file?

Comment: Why would you ever need to find a .class file? You can always access those directly unless you're trying to do something strange like a bootloader, but I'm not clear why you actually need it?